# Sending Push Notifications When a Firebase Real Time Database Node is Updated

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, notifications

I have created an app which uses firebase real-time database and storage. My app allows users to message each other, but I am not sure how to notify the user when they have received a new message. I store all of the messages in one node called messages. I then store the message relationships in a different node called "user-messages". How do I monitor the "user-messages" node to alert the user with a notification that they have a new message? I am familiar with observing event types and such, i.e.: .Value and .ChildAdded, but I am not sure how to trigger an event to send the user a notification.

edit: gave a little more clairity.

Comment: follow https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-audience

Comment: I'm not sure how that answers my question. That only allows me to send a push notification to a specific list of users.

Answer (score 2):

So I accidently did not see that Firebase can use Google Cloud Messaging which seems to be able to do what I want. For future reference firebase has put the IOS setup here :[Firebase Cloud Messaging SetUp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)

Comment: I was not able to get this to do what I wanted so I ended using an SDK from One Signal and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned, you can use `child_added` event to monitor whenever a new message is added to `user-messages` and `firebase` will call your event handler whenever a new child is added.

```
ref.child('user-messages').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
  // Read the message and send notification here
})
```

You may want to update the `user-message` as well after it has been handled so that you don't end up sending duplicate notifications when your app restarts.

Comment: I need it to alert the user when the app isn't running or when the app is in the background.

Comment: This should be happening on the server side. So, it won't matter if the app isn't running or in the background.

Comment: I think we may be talking past each other here. The snapshots only take place when you put them in a function and then call that function or you do it when the view has loaded or will load. This means the observer will only observe the database when called. This means that the user cannot get an alert unless they are on that view and the app has to be running. I need something that can observe my database when the app isn't running and then send the user a notification if the node is updated.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was set up an XMPP server with Ejabbered in order to conduct notifications. Hope the following helps.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-the-xmpp-connection-server-protocol

Comment: I don't have even the faintest clue on how to set up an XMPP server. I tried to set up ejabbered but it won't even let me authenticate. What did you use to get you started. I looked at the docs for firebase, but I didn't know how to do what they said